# Consider a binary operation $\circ:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\times\{1,2,\ldots, n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms

Consider a binary operation $\circ:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\times\{1,2,\ldots, n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Сall the degree of associativity of this operation the number of triples $i, j, k$ such ,that
$$(i\circ j)\circ k = i \circ(j\circ k)$$

We have a numbers $n, x$. Suggest a polynomial in $n$ algorithm that will construct an operation having an associativity degree equal to $x$ or report that it does not exist.

I'm trying to figure it out, but I don't see what criteria you can come up with to make an operation have the right degree of associativity.

Comment: Interesting problem. Which context did you find it in? (For example, if it's an exercise in a particular chapter of a textbook or lecture notes, which kind of ideas did that chapter teach?)

Comment: Yes, it's a really interesting problem. This is a bonus problem from the theme about a class of polynomial languages. I'm just wondering how to solve it.